# Sed Capture Group Regex

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have the following string as output

```
Config(1) = ( value1:4000 value2:2000 value3:500 value4:1000)
```

I want to capture all 4 values into 4 different variables in bash and I think the cleanest way to do that is with regex. And I think the best way to use regex for this is with sed. 
I have tested the regex and can capture the value1 with

```
value1:(\d+)
```

With sed I am trying this based on other answers:

```
echo "Config(1) = ( value1:4000 value2:2000 value3:500 value4:1000)" | sed -n 's/^\s*value1\:\(\d\+\)\s\?.*/\1/p'
```

This returns nothing

Comment: `^\s*value1\...` This is suppose to return nothing, as you're matching start of string followed by space character followed by `value1`, which clearly isn't you string, you have to consider `Config(1)` also in your pattern

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BASH supports regular expressions natively:

```
#!/bin/bash

s='Config(1) = ( value1:4000 value2:2000 value3:500 value4:1000)'
pattern='value1:([0-9]+) value2:([0-9]+) value3:([0-9]+) value4:([0-9]+)'

if [[ "$s" =~ $pattern ]]
then
        echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
        echo "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
        echo "${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
        echo "${BASH_REMATCH[4]}"
fi
```

```
4000
2000
500
1000
```

Answer (score 0):

You could grep for the value with the `-o` flag to only output the match.

This outputs `4000`

```sh
echo "Config(1) = ( value1:4000 value2:2000 value3:500 value4:1000)" | grep -Po '(?<=value1:)\d+'
```

Though it's tough to advise about if its the cleanest way to achieve your goal without more context, a program (in `awk` maybe?) that parses that output format might be interesting here.

Answer (score 0):

**This will work**
Create a simple two statement script

```
var=`echo "Config(1) = ( value1:4000 value2:2000 value3:500 value4:1000)" | grep -Eo "\( .*\)"|sed 's/^.\(.*\).$/\1/'`
for v in $var; do
 echo $v| awk -F: '{print $2}'
done
```

Run as

```
root@114855-T480:/home/yadav22ji# ./tpr
4000
2000
500
1000
```

You can assign these values to variables as you said.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing and capturing every value to the variable:

```
result=`echo "Config(1) = ( value1:4000 value2:2000 value3:500 value4:1000)"`
declare -A variables=( ["variableone"]="1" ["variabletwo"]="2" ["variablethree"]="3" ["variablefour"]="4" )
for index in ${!variables[*]}
do
    export $index=$(echo $result | tr ' ' '\n' | sed "s/[()]//g" |  grep value | awk -F ":" '{print $2}' | head -"${variables[$index]}" | tail -1)
done
```

Array item- name of the variable

Array index - counter line using in head command

```
[root@centos ~]# env | grep variable
variablefour=1000
variableone=4000
variabletwo=2000
variablethree=500
```

Answer (score 0):

I think following regex could be more shorter form in @hmm answer

> value[0-9]{1}:([0-9]+)